# PHP Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php, syntax, parse-error

HI getting an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/crafru/public_html/test/damienform.php on line 124

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="en-gb" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
.table-style1 {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 39%;
    height: 197px;
}
.table-style2 {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 25px;
}
.table-style3 {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 221px;
    height: 25px;
}
.table-style4 {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 221px;
    height: 25px;
}
.table-style5 {
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #EBF4FB">
<?php
    $submitrunnertime= $_POST['submitrunnertime'];
    $RunnerID= $_POST['RunnerID'];
    $EventID= $_POST['EventID'];
    $Date= $_POST['Date'];
    $Time= $_POST['Time'];
    $Position= $_POST['Position'];
    $CategoryID= $_POST['CategoryID'];
    $AgeGrade= $_POST['AgeGrade'];
    $PB= $_POST['PB'];
    $submitrunnertime= $_POST['submitrunnertime'];
    $Test = "pass";

    $host= 'localhost';
    $user= '****';  
    $password= '****';
    $database= '****';

/**
    Function: connect to a database.
    $host = hostname to connect to e.g. 'localhost'
    $id = username identity, e.g. 'ta589'
    $pwd = user password, e.g. 'twiggy9'
    $db = database to use, e.g. 'ta589'
    Returns the database connection.
**/

function connect_db($host, $user, $password, $database) {
    $connection = @mysql_connect($host, $id, $pwd)
        or die('connection problem:' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db)
        or die('db selection problem:' . mysql_error());
    return $connection;
?>

<table class="table-style1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style3">Feild</td>
        <td class="table-style2">Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">Runner ID </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$RunnerID?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">Event ID </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$EventID?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">Date </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$Date?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">Time </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$Time?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">Position </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$Position?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">Category ID </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$CategoryID?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">Age Grade </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$AgeGrade?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">PB </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$PB?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">submitrunnertime </td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$submitrunnertime?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table-style4">Test - Remove this</td>
        <td class="table-style5"><?=$Test?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Been looking at this and can't see any missing end bits.  What am i missing?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: It a very simple error, My advice is use an IDE like ZendStudio or Netbeans .. you would easily spot such error. The error occurred becasue of missing `}` in your `connect_db()`

Comment: @Baba Actually, in this case NetBeans didn't indicate an error (for me, at least); the formatting was a little off, but no red underlines or other error indicators.

Comment: what version are you using @Matt

Comment: @Baba disregard; error indicator is on the last line.

Comment: @Matt .. cool .. i was curios myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a closing 'stache on your function.

```
function connect_db($host, $user, $password, $database) {
    $connection = @mysql_connect($host, $id, $pwd)
      or die('connection problem:' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db)
      or die('db selection problem:' . mysql_error());
    return $connection;
} //<--THAT ONE

?>
```